# View to display nodes with lat long in proximity of specific lat long

Tags: location

I have a content type and it has a geolocation field which stores a lat long . If I create one node with some lat / long info, I need to  look up / show a view of other nodes that have lat long information which is in the proximity of the former's lat long info. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I've used the Location Module (www.drupal.org/project/location) on Drupal 6 and it allowed for proximity based Views.  Was that the module that gave no joy?  If not you may want to look into it.

Comment: For future reference, the Location module is pretty rubbish in Drupal 7 - especially when you stack it against other geocoding options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Geolocation Proximity](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation_proximity) seems to be exactly a solution for you. You will need to keep location data using [Geolocation Field](https://drupal.org/project/geolocation) to benefit from it.

Current features are:

> - Views filter that can be used to filter entities (nodes, users, etc.) based on distance from a certain point (defined as lat/lng point). The input widget is very basic at the moment. Patches welcome...
> - Views field to display the calculated distance between the entity and a reference point (can be synced with filters' lat/lng values).
> - User-friendly input widget for exposed filters using Google's reverse geocoder

Big lacking features are:

- HTML 5 Geolocation input
- proximity SQL look ups

It's competitor is [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations) module. It's a suite that uses Google Maps API. One of it's functions is:

> **Getlocations Search** which uses Google Geocoding on entered search terms and shows nearby locations. The search form is fully configurable with options for **setting the Search distance**, Distance units, Number of locations to show and Restrict the search to a content type.

Emphasis mine.

Last but not least, you can use [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field). It can be calculated on access, so it is perfectly possible to make PHP computed field displaying "distance from X" where X is defined on the fly. You will need to write computation in PHP, but you will not be tied to any particular [metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Metric.html).